# How can I draw a Gantt chart in Google Chart Tools?

Tags: google-visualization

I am trying to implement a Gantt chart using Google Chart Tools, but I have not found the correct option in Google. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be a Gantt Chart control out of the box.

https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery

However you can use the Google Chart Tool API to create a Gantt Chart, see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/2jfy6/2/

Code

```
<img  

title="Gantt Chart" 
src="http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bhs&amp;
chs=500x300&amp;
chd=t:0,0,0,0,0,0|10,20,30,40,60,75|10,20,40,20,30,19&amp;
chxt=x,y&amp;
chxl=1:sad|Testing&amp;
chxr=0,0,100|1,0,100&amp;
chds=0,100&amp;
chco=DC143C|DC143C,ffffff00&amp;
chg=20,50&amp;
chbh=20,10&amp;
chtt=Gantt Chart&amp;
chts=000000,25&amp;
chdl=Project Test&amp;chdlp=b" 
alt="Google Charts Gantt Chart"
width="500" 
height="300" />
```