# google chart script for time table/bar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

How to write a code to draw google chart of the time bar. The bar has a start point and the length, and a function like TimeBar(start time, duration). Have looked for the sample codes on Google, but no lucky. Thanks.

[image: Pic[1]]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [Charts Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/) in Google Apps Script, you are limited to the chart types provided by the service. You won't be able to create your specific visualization there.

In HTML / Javascript, you might be able to get close to what you want using the technique described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13931613/1677912).

Using the [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/) outside of Apps Script, you can create your own Chart App or Gadget, using the Google Visualization API.

> **How do I create a new Chart gadget?**
>       The best way to get started is to first get familiar with the [Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/), and then read the [Gadget Extensions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/gadgets) section and
>   start coding.